# Select all Next to with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to parse through html and would to get all `<h3>...</h3>` next to `<table>...</table>`, but have only gotten the first `<h3></h3><table></table>` from `$('h3 + table', thecontents)`. Also, what if we wanted the `h3` based on it's contents (ie. Friday, Dec. 14, Saturday, Dec. 15, ...)?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('...') + '&callback=?', function(data){
        var thecontents = data.contents;
        var required = $('h3 + table', thecontents).html();
        $("#hello").html("<pre>" + required + "</pre>");
    });
});
```

The contents of `thecontents` or `data.contents` is

```
<html>
...
<h3><strong>Friday, Dec. 14</strong></h3>
<table>...</table>
...
<h3>...</h3>
<table>...</table>
</html>
```

My current website returns `required` or `$('h3 + table', thecontents).html()`

```
<html>
<body id="hello">
<pre>
    <p></p>
    ...
    <p></p>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking at the `original website` structure, don't you want the **previous** `h3` (or heading) of every `table`?

Comment: @Shidersz Yes, exactly, I want the previous h3 of each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to convert or `parse string to html` is wrong, it should be like this

```
var thecontents = $('<div></div>').html(data.contents)
```

After parse to get `h3` and `table` but the previous element of `table` should be `h3` you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('...') + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    var thecontents = document.createElement('html')
    thecontents.innerHTML = data.contents;
    var required = $(thecontents).find('h3 + table');

    var theResults = '';
    $.each(required, function(i, obj) {
      // .prev() used to get previous sibling or h3
      theResults += $(obj).prev()[0].outerHTML + '\n';
      // the table
      theResults += obj.outerHTML + '\n';
    })

    $("#hello").html("<pre>" + theResults + "</pre>");
  });
});
```

it using `.outerHTML` to get string like `<h3>Title</h3>` while `.html()` will return `innerHTML` or `Title` only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/#next-selector)  `$("table").next("h3")` to get h3 next to the table and

```
$("table").next("h3").filter(function() {  
  return $(this).text().indexOf('Friday')!==-1
})
```

to [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the h3 by its text.

```js
console.log('finding text', $("table").next("h3").filter(function() {  
  return $(this).text().indexOf('Friday')!==-1
}).length);
console.log('next', $("table").next("h3").length);

console.log('prev', $("table").prev("h3").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<table></table>
<h3>1</h3>
<table></table>
<h3>2</h3>
<table></table>
<h3><strong>Friday, Dec. 14</strong></h3>
<div></div>
</html>
```

EDIT:

as you want to get the hr and table with string you can use regex

```js
var dataString = '<table></table> <h3>1</h3> <table></table> <h3>2</h3> <table></table> <h3><strong>Friday, Dec. 14</strong></h3> <div></div>';

var regExp = /<\s*h3[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*h3>\s?<\s*table[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*table>/g;
do {
    var m = regExp.exec(dataString);
    if (m) {
    debugger;
        console.log(m[0]);
    }
} while (m);
```

Comment: What if <h3> is always before <table> ?

Comment: if it is before then you need to use `prev`

Comment: @HelloWorld check my snippet

Comment: Thanks you for helping -- prev works. I'm having a hard time implementing it though. How would you use this over the thecontents variable?

Comment: @HelloWorld depends what you have in your data.contents?

Comment: It's the whole website in HTML including the h3, tables, etc

Comment: @HelloWorld seems to be confusing for me, why would you load whole website and try to create snippet of your problem first.

Comment: So sorry, I'm really new to JavaScript/jQuery. It's the only way I know how to do it. If you could show me how to only get a snippet of the website back, it would be a big help.

Comment: Essentially, I'm getting info from another url say apple.com and there's a bunch of '<h3></h3><table></table>' 's. But, I just want to get the <h3> and <tables>'s from the site and if wanted, filter by the <h3>.

Comment: data.contents is an array or its a string?

Comment: data.contents is a string

Comment: Thanks for trying! I'm getting null.

Comment: @HelloWorld understand my answer and implement on your own, you need do the changes as per your data, because your question is quite not clear with the minimal example, so you need to understand and apply \

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample as below. This will add in the same document. You can change as per your need.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>   
</head>

<body>
    <h3><strong>Friday, Dec. 14</strong></h3>
    <table></table>
    <h3><strong>Sunday, Dec. 14</strong></h3>
    <table></table>
    <h3><strong>SatFriday, Dec. 14</strong></h3>
    <table></table>
    <h3><strong>SatFriday, Dec. 14</strong></h3>
    <table></table>

    <div id="hello">

    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#hello').append('<pre>');
        $('#hello pre').append('<p>');
        $(document.body).find($('table')).each(function (a, b) {
            $('#hello pre p').append($(this).prev('h3').html()).append(b);
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for 
https://api.jquery.com/next/

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

and in script you can get it by,

```
$( "li.third-item" ).next().css( "background-color", "red" );
```